# What is the difference between liftM and mapM in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, combinators

What is the difference between the functions liftM and mapM?

Comment: @larsmans That question has nothing to do with mapM.

Comment: @mgiuca: you're right. Excuse me. I should read more carefully, I guess.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First, the types differ:

```
liftM :: (Monad m) => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
mapM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
```

`liftM` lifts a function of type `a -> b` to a monadic counterpart.
`mapM` applies a function which yields a monadic value to a list of values, yielding list of results embedded in the monad.

Examples:

```
> liftM (map toUpper) getLine
Hallo
"HALLO"

> :t mapM return "monad"
mapM return "monad" :: (Monad m) => m [Char]
```

... note that `map` and `mapM` differ! E.g.

```
> map (x -> [x+1]) [1,2,3]
[[2],[3],[4]]
> mapM (x -> [x+1]) [1,2,3]
[[2,3,4]]
```

Comment: Is it `(\x -> [x + 1])` in the lambda for map? I tried the syntax without backslash for x and I get `Pattern syntax in expression context: x -> [x + 1]`. I am a Haskell newbie so I might be missing something here.

Answer (score 36):

They aren't really related. I'll try to explain what each of them does. I assume you have a basic understanding of what a monad is.

`liftM :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> (m a -> m b)`  lets you use an ordinary function in a monad. It takes a function `a -> b`, and turns it into a function `m a -> m b`, that does exactly the same thing as the original function, but does it in a monad. The resulting function doesn't "do" anything to the monad (it can't, because the original function didn't know it was in a monad). For example:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    output <- liftM ("Hello, " ++) getLine
    putStrLn output
```

The function `("Hello, " ++) :: String -> String` prepends "Hello, " to a string. Passing it to `liftM` creates a function of type `IO String -> IO String` -- now you have a function that works in the IO monad. It doesn't do any IO, but it can take an IO action as input, and produces an IO action as output. Therefore, I can pass `getLine` as input, and it will call `getLine`, prepend "Hello, " to the front of the result, and return that as an IO action.

`mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]` is quite different; note that unlike `liftM`, it takes a monadic function. For example, in the IO monad, it has type `(a -> IO b) -> [a] -> IO [b]`. It is very much like the ordinary `map` function, only it applies a monadic action to a list, and produces a result list wrapped in a monadic action. For example (a pretty bad one):

```
main2 :: IO ()
main2 = do
    output <- mapM (putStrLn . show) [1, 2, 3]
    putStrLn (show output)
```

This prints:

```
1
2
3
[(),(),()]
```

What it is doing is iterating over the list, applying `(putStrLn . show)` to each element in the list (having the IO effect of printing out each of the numbers), and also transforming the numbers into the `()` value. The resulting list consists of `[(), (), ()]` -- the output of `putStrLn`.

Comment: Additionally, if you only care about the monadic effects of `mapM`, and not about the returned list, you can use `mapM_`. The `mapM_` function has type `Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()`, it is useful in the putStrLn example, where you're probably not interested in the list of units.

Comment: @Tom Lokhorst Yep, that's right. (I couldn't come up with a useful example where the result is important on the IO monad.)

Comment: Why does mapM transform the numbers into '()'?

Comment: @Luke The `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()` returns a unit value (that is the `()`). Here's another example: `mapM (\x -> putStrLn (show x) >> return (x + 1)) [1, 2, 3]`. This returns a list of Ints instead of units.

Answer (score 11):

The other answers have already explained it well, so I will just point out that you will usually see `fmap` used instead of `liftM` in real Haskell code, as `fmap` is just a more general version in the type class `Functor`. As all well-behaved `Monad`s should be instances of `Functor` as well, they should be equivalent.

You may also see the operator `<$>` used as a synonym for `fmap`.

Also, `mapM f = sequence . map f`, so you can think of it as turning a list of values into a list of actions, and then running the actions one after another, collecting the results in a list.

Answer (score 7):

`liftM` and `mapM` are quite different, as you can see via their types and their implementation:

```
mapM         :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
mapM f as    =  sequence (map f as)

liftM        :: (Monad m) => (a1 -> r) -> m a1 -> m r
liftM f m1   = do { x1 <- m1; return (f x1) }
```

so while `mapM` applies a monadic function to each element of a list, `liftM` applies a function in a monadic setting.